# Which type of hosting/server to get for 100 wordpress blogs with 30000 daily unique visitors?

Tags: web-hosting, server, webserver, looking-for-hosting, cloud-hosting

I am launching 100 Wordpress text based blog websites with light themes on them. I expect to get 30000 daily unique visitors with an estimated peak of 1000 simultaneous visitors across all sites.

Roughly speaking, what type of hosting would be best suitable for my requirement? Shared, VPS, Dedicated or Cloud?

I am a web developer but I have always been confused about what server technicalities.

I recently got shared hosting from multiple providers and I ran only 5 small and standard Wordpress sites on each and on both of them I crossed the I/O usage (1mb) and entry processes limit (128 num). And this and other tecnical aspects of servers is where I am unable to understand what to do. I don't want to blindly upgrade to best possible hosting as I want to stay economical as well.

Comment: The hosting you needs depends significantly on how heavy your sites are (Wordpress sites are relatively heavy, but with HUGE variation depending on their functionality and how they are put together).   Regardless, you are definitely looking at the high end - and likely multiple machines.     Your 1000 simultaneous visitors on 30k daily unique visitors seems somewhat unlikely - and if that is the case you will be wanting to consider maximum time-to-load for the peak...

Comment: If you have the luxury of time, you may be best served by starting with a handful of sites and monitoring the CPU load, memory, bandwidth and disk IO, then gradually adding more sites and seeing how it scales.

Comment: The 100 sites is unlkely an issue - a moderately specced VPS will do you here.  The killer will be the peak loading.   You may want to look at caching and/or a CDN to offload some of the peak load.   I have in the region of 100 average (some heavy, some light) sites on a 16 VCPU with 32 gigs of memory and SSD disk and my system does not break a sweat - although my memory usage is very much on the heavy side due to the way its configured.   That said, I would never see anything close to 1000 simultaneous visitors.

Comment: If you have 1000 simultaneous visitors you would want upwards of 4000 simultaneous processes (1000 users each using 4 threads to download main page and images).   This will require a lot of memory - but exactly how much depends on the way the webserver is configured.

Comment: There is a massive difference between serving 1000 visitors over a 10 minute period and a 1000 visitors simultaneously. You really need to get a grip on this aspect as a starting point.  Lets assume each web page is 1megabyte in size - at 1000 simultaneous visitors you will need  roughly a 10000 megabit (10 gigabit) connection to service all those requests  within 1 second - ignoring the massive CPU and IO requirements.  If you spread this out evenly over 10 minutes that figure goes down to less then 20 megabit.